# How to convert the tuple to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to convert the flowing tuple (I am not sure if it is really tuple) to pandas DF by different approach but I could not do that. Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```py
Please note that my columns should be:
"USGS:06730500:00060:00003","USGS:06730500:00060:00003_qualifiers", "datetimeUTC"
            longmont_discharge = hf.extract_nwis_df(longmont_resp)
            longmont_discharge
```

Here is the output:

```py
Output:
(                                             USGS:06730500:00060:00003  \
 datetimeUTC                                            
 1946-05-10 00:00:00+00:00                      16.00   
 1946-05-11 00:00:00+00:00                      19.00   
 1946-05-12 00:00:00+00:00                       9.00   
 1946-05-13 00:00:00+00:00                       3.00   
 1946-05-14 00:00:00+00:00                       7.80   
 ...                                              ...   
 2018-08-25 00:00:00+00:00                       9.86   
 2018-08-26 00:00:00+00:00                       7.02   
 2018-08-27 00:00:00+00:00                       4.05   
 2018-08-28 00:00:00+00:00                       2.67   
 2018-08-29 00:00:00+00:00                       3.36   
                                     USGS:06730500:00060:00003_qualifiers  
 datetimeUTC                                                     
 1946-05-10 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 1946-05-11 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 1946-05-12 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 1946-05-13 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 1946-05-14 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 ...                                                        ...  
 2018-08-25 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 2018-08-26 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 2018-08-27 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 2018-08-28 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 2018-08-29 00:00:00+00:00                                    A  
 
 [26410 rows x 2 columns],
 {'USGS:06730500': {'siteName': 'BOULDER CREEK AT MOUTH NEAR LONGMONT, CO',
   'siteLatLongSrs': {'srs': 'EPSG:4326',
    'latitude': 40.13877778,
    'longitude': -105.0202222},
   'timeSeries': {'00060': {'variableFreq': '<Day>',
     'variableUnit': 'ft3/s',
     'variableDescription': 'Discharge, cubic feet per second',
     'methodID': '17666',
     'methodDescription': ''}}}})
```

Here is my method to convert it to df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(longmont_discharge, columns=[ "USGS:06730500:00060:00003",
                                             "USGS:06730500:00060:00003_qualifiers","datetimeUTC"])
```

I also tried df = pd.DataFrame.from_records And Here is the error I get:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-5bed67d5f15e> in <module>
      1 #Convert tuple into Pandas DF:
----> 2 df = pd.DataFrame(longmont_discharge, columns=[ "USGS:06730500:00060:00003",
      3                                                "USGS:06730500:00060:00003_qualifiers", "datetimeUTC"])

~\anaconda3\envs\myenvearthpy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    709                     )
    710                 else:
--> 711                     mgr = ndarray_to_mgr(
    712                         data,
    713                         index,

~\anaconda3\envs\myenvearthpy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in ndarray_to_mgr(values, index, columns, dtype, copy, typ)
    302         # by definition an array here
    303         # the dtypes will be coerced to a single dtype
--> 304         values = _prep_ndarray(values, copy=copy)
    305 
    306     if dtype is not None and not is_dtype_equal(values.dtype, dtype):

~\anaconda3\envs\myenvearthpy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _prep_ndarray(values, copy)
    538         # and platform dtype preservation
    539         if is_list_like(values[0]):
--> 540             values = np.array([convert(v) for v in values])
    541         elif isinstance(values[0], np.ndarray) and values[0].ndim == 0:
    542             # GH#21861 see test_constructor_list_of_lists

~\anaconda3\envs\myenvearthpy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    538         # and platform dtype preservation
    539         if is_list_like(values[0]):
--> 540             values = np.array([convert(v) for v in values])
    541         elif isinstance(values[0], np.ndarray) and values[0].ndim == 0:
    542             # GH#21861 see test_constructor_list_of_lists

~\anaconda3\envs\myenvearthpy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in convert(v)
    531 
    532             v = extract_array(v, extract_numpy=True)
--> 533             res = maybe_convert_platform(v)
    534             return res
    535 

~\anaconda3\envs\myenvearthpy\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in maybe_convert_platform(values)
    122         arr = values
    123 
--> 124     if arr.dtype == object:
    125         arr = cast(np.ndarray, arr)
    126         arr = lib.maybe_convert_objects(arr)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample of your input?

Answer (score 0):

From the output you show, it looks like a tuple containing two items:

1. A Pandas dataframe (with two columns, not 3)
2. A dictionary containing meta data.

You could verify this using the following commands:

```
print(type(longmont_discharge))
print(len(longmont_discharge))
print([type(item) for item in longmont_discharge])
```

If it is a tuple containing a dataframe and a dictionary, then try this:

```
df, info = longmont_discharge
```

Sounds like you need to do a tutorial on Python tuples and how to index their elements.  And check out [this tutorial on tuple unpacking](https://realpython.com/lessons/tuple-assignment-packing-unpacking/).  This is the technique I used above to assign the contents of the tuple to variables.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did run the code and here is the result:
```python

Input: 
print(type(longmont_discharge))
print(len(longmont_discharge))
print([type(item) for item in longmont_discharge])

Output:
<class 'tuple'>
2
[<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, <class 'dict'>]

```

But the df, info code returned the same result:

I would like to have a table which looks like the one goven in the following link:
https://github.com/Ali-UPT/test.git

I must have three columns. Can you please let me know how to tackle this issue?

Comment: This confirms the type, size and contents of the tuple. As @AdamRadounis said, you will have to provide us with some code to generate `longmont_discharge` because I can't know whether the `df` extracted using my answer is the dataframe you want or not. Please add this to the question.

Comment: @Ali Have you reviewed the tutorial I linked to in my answer? Do you understand tuple unpacking now?

Comment: Yes, I have but it did not help that much.